# Unable to debug web app using VS 2010 on IE 8 after downgrade from IE 11

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging

I recently downgraded IE from 11 to 8 due to IE 11 not having the ability to run as previous versions. After the downgrade, I suddenly was not able to debug a web app from Visual Studio 2010. While using IE 11, I was still able to hit breakpoints in the JavaScript code but now, none of my breakpoints are hit and instead when I navigate to the page where I think the error is, I get a pop up window titled Webpage Error with a message of "Do you want to debug this webpage? This webpage contains errors that might prevent it from displaying or working correctly. If you are not testing this webpage, click No." I've never seen this pop up appear while using IE 11 or the IE version before I upgraded to IE 11.

Is there an IIS setting that gets overridden by downgrading? I'm using IIS 7.5. How can I get back to seeing my breakpoints getting hit in VS2010?

Update:

In VS 2010, while in debugging mode, I clicked Debug > Attach to Process and noticed two processes for iexplorer.exe. On that is grayed out (which I'm assuming there is a debugger attached to) but has no title. And the other has a title that matches what I see in the actual IE window. Back in IE, when I see the error popup asking me if I want to debug this web page and I click yes, I get a new popup with the title of Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger with the message that includes "An unhandled exception .... occured in iexplorer.exe[4508]. This process ID matches that of the grayed out iexplorer process. Why would there be two iexplorer processes?

I have VS 2012 installed as well but not sure if that changes anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Going all the way back to IE8 is overkill-- use IE10 instead. The IE team removed the "emulation" features from the pre-release IE11 developer tools because the emulations were *never* very accurate; you should instead use VMs instead (see http://modern.ie)

All versions of IE since IE8 use [two or more processes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx): One process is the Manager/Frame process and one or more processes represent the tab/content processes where your HTML and script run. You want your debugger to attach to the tab/content process, which is a child of the manager/frame process.

The "Do you want to debug" prompt is controlled by Tools > Internet Options > Advanced; see the 2 "Script debugger" checkboxes near the top of the list.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for that tidbit on IE 8 and two or more processes. I learned something today. I'm actually using IE 9 now, my work requires that I use IE 8 or 9. I tried your suggestion with attaching the debugger to the tab/content process (or the iexplorer process with the higher process id out of the two) but it didn't work. I still got the pop up window asking me if I wanted to debug the web page. So my breakpoints are still not getting hit. I've also unchecked both checkboxes in Tools > Internet Options > Advanced for disabling JavaScript debugging.

Comment: Did you have VS launch IE or did you launch it standalone? VS passes additional debugger info into IE when it launches it.

Comment: I click the green arrow (F5) in VS2010 and it launches IE 9. I think the problem is that the debugger is not properly attaching to the process somehow.